# "Multi-part identifier cannot be bound" in Crystal Reports with SQL Expressions/Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports, which enables you to create things called SQL Expressions.  They are basically subqueries, but limited so that each SQL Expression can only return a scalar value.  For more info, here: http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/07/crystal-reports-using-sql-expression-fields/

The referenced article says very specifically that:

```
If you are using a SQL Expression as a subquery and wish to link it to the 
detail row of your main report, do not include the table you wish to link to 
in the FROM clause of the subquery. For example:

(
SELECT  MAX("FLOWSHEET"."VALUE")
FROM    FLOWSHEET
WHERE   "FLOWSHEET"."ID" in ('11')
AND "FLOWSHEET"."IP_ID" = "HOSPITAL_VISIT"."IP_ID"
)

The above query links to the HOSPITAL_VISIT table in the main report by 
linking to the IP_ID field. To accomplish this, HOSPITAL_VISIT is omitted 
from the FROM clause in the query.
```

I have a main query in my report that says:

```
SELECT
hp.MovedInDate, 
c.LastName, 
c.FirstName,
chp.ClientID
FROM   
chp 
INNER JOIN hp ON chp.HousePlacementID = hp.HousePlacementID
INNER JOIN c ON chp.ClientID = c.ClientID
```

Now I want to add a SQL Expression

```
(
SELECT TOP 1 AssessmentAcuityType
FROM a
WHERE a.ClientID = chp.ClientID
AND a.AssessmentTool = 'SPDAT'
AND a.AssessmentToolType NOT LIKE '%VI%'
AND a.IntakeDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month,-6,hp.MovedInDate) AND hp.MovedInDate
ORDER BY IntakeID DESC
)
```

When I do so, I get the error `The multi-part identifier hp.MovedInDate cannot be bound`

So although I know I didn't define hp in my subquery, the rules of SQL Expression fields state that I shouldn't.  Anyone able to help me understand how to fix this error?

Comment: At a glance, the query looks fine. What's the structure of `HIFIS_HousePlacements`? Does it really contain a `MovedInDate`?

Comment: @stickybit yes, it really does contain `MovedInDate` which is a datetime field, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried a simpler expression to check if the functionality exists and works as expected. Like, commenting out all the 'and' and 'Order by' clauses..?

Comment: @ShivSidhu I tried commenting out all of it and now I get a "The multi-part identifier HIFIS_Clients_HousePlacements.ClientID cannot be bound"

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you add the expression to your main query?   My guess is you're not doing it in the right way to get it to correlate with your main query.

Comment: @TabAlleman So we have a ClientID, that represents a Client. My main query is listing all clients that have a Housing Placement.  In other words, they Moved In on a particular date.

Prior to the move-in, they were Assessed and given an AcuityType. However, they may have been assessed multiple times.  I want the most recent assessment for each client that fits certain criteria.  It's CR, so I have a bunch of available fields, and the SQL expression is one of them, so I list it next to the ClientID and the MoveInDate.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved part of the problem.

Part of the problem relies on the *order* of the *sides* of the equation.

So I've determined that this results in an error:

```
(
SELECT TOP 1 AssessmentAcuityType
FROM a
WHERE a.ClientID = chp.ClientID
)
```

And this does not

```
(
SELECT TOP 1 AssessmentAcuityType
FROM a
WHERE chp.ClientID = a.ClientID
)
```